# Translating DNS Server Replys because of multiple NAT Networks

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, rewrite, nat

I am planning and building a large infrastructure wich different natted networks.

Lets say I have a datacenter network `10.0.0.0/24` and I have many different customer networks that could be anything (i.e. `192.168.0.0/24` or even `10.0.0.0/24`), so I need to NAT all the traffic on our firewall in the datacenter and on the firewall from the customer. So that both directions do not try to access `10.0.0.0/24` adresses to get to the other side.

Now when I try to implement DNS forwarder the customers DNS will always reply with internal adresses, which are not reachable from datacenter. I somehow need a DNS rewrite for specific DNS forwarders.

For me it seemed like a normal feature so I didn't worry about. Now I could not find any DNS server that is able to do a DNS Rewrite per different DNS Forwarders ( or I'm searching for the wrong keywords).

Do you know any DNS Server that could do the Job? I currently have Windows 2012 DNS Servers but I would use any that could do the job (Bind or something equal is fine).

I know that there is an option on the firewall from the customers site to NAT DNS Replys but this is no option as there a lot of customers with many different Firewalls and I dont think they all support this feature. (Do you think so as well?)

Any thoughts on this? Thank you!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this is all static NAT translation that will only change class C Network, the host will be the same IP.

Comment: _"Any thoughts on this?"_ -- yeah - don't do it :(

Comment: Well Alnitak, this is no option as there need to be NAT and DNS implemented. Do you have any better idea or do you have expierence in how many firewall types do implement this NAT DNS Translating feature?

Comment: It's not clear why you need it, nor why you assert that the customers DNS will always reply with internal addresses.  What you describe (at the IP level) sounds a lot like Amazon's EC2 hosting, and AFAIK they don't use any "stupid DNS tricks" (tm) to achieve it.

Comment: I need because I am building a larger Network environment with many different customers. The networks do overlapp, therefore I need double NAT translation (which is absolutly no problem). Now I want to use DNS over the different NAT networks. The Customers DNS will reply with internal IPs because he does not know about the NAT in the VPN connection. As I said, I know there is a feature that will translate DNS Replys at the NAT transforming firewall, but I dont think that all the different firewalls implement this feature, so I try to find a workarround.

Comment: You will need to use split view DNS and configure manually what networks see what view. You can't NAT your DNS responses.